# Maintain executable file permissions when uploading binaries to a github release

Tags: github, file-permissions, github-release

I'm adding binaries to a release in github by dragging and dropping them into the binaries upload section when creating a new release. The binaries have the following permissions on my local (OSX):

`-rwxr-xr-x   1 user  group  100 Mar 22 00:00 file1
-rwxr-xr-x   1 user  group  100 Mar 22 00:00 file2
-rwxr-xr-x   1 user  group  100 Mar 22 00:00 file3
-rwxr-xr-x   1 user  group  100 Mar 22 00:00 file4`

However when I download the binary from Releases the file mode has changed:

`-rw-r--r--@   1 user  group   100 Mar 22 09:00 file1`

Has this been documented anywhere? Is there a way to preserve file permissions when uploading binaries to github?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a way to preserve file permissions when uploading binaries to github?

I don't believe so. People that download the file will need to `chmod +x` to get the execute permission back. A file's permission is not stored within the file itself, rather it is an attribute of the file on the file system.

If you really need to preserve complex permissions for files, I would suggest storing the files in a container that preserve permissions. Like a DMG for macOS, and uploading the DMG instead.